# Check if object of base class came from subclass

Tags: c#, inheritance, types, casting

I have a base class and a bunch of subclasses of it.

I have an object of base class and I know that it was an instance of one of the subclasses before, but it was casted to the base class.

I want to know how to discover which subclass it was before. More specifically:

```
SubClass sc = new SubClass();
BaseClass bc = sc;

if(bs was SubClass) print("bc was SubClass");
```

How can I write this `if` correctly? Is it even possible?

Comment: The answer you've accepted does not work for all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `is` DOES NOT WORK.

It does not "discover which subclass it was before", just that it can be cast to the given type.

Take these class definitions:

```
public class BaseClass { }
public class IntermediateClass : BaseClass { }
public class SubClass : IntermediateClass { }
```

I can write this code and it gets it WRONG:

```
SubClass sc = new SubClass();
BaseClass bc = sc;

if (bc is IntermediateClass)
{
    Console.WriteLine("bc is IntermediateClass");
}
```

It tells me that `bc is IntermediateClass`, but it's not. It's a `BaseClass`.

The only way to do it is a direct equality comparison.

This works:

```
if (bc.GetType() == typeof(SubClass))
{
    Console.WriteLine("bc is Subclass");
}
```

Comment: @Daniel if it returns null, then it means that there is no object in the list is instantiated from the type `T`

Comment: @Daniel - What type is `T`? If it's a generic type then are you explicitly providing it in the call? You'll need show me the full code you're trying. Everything I posted was tested before posting. I know my code works.

Comment: @Daniel - please don't delete comments. They provide context for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

[`is` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator)

> The `is` operator checks if the result of an expression is compatible with a given type.

```cs
SubClass sc = new SubClass();
BaseClass bc = sc;

if (bc is SubClass)
    Console.WriteLine("bc is a Subclass");
```

#### update

this only check if `bc` is castable to `Subclass`(subclass is one of the parents types). Although I still see that the word [is-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) still valid.

But as mentioned by @Enigmativity to be more accurate if you ask about the creating source type

```cs
if (bc.GetType() == typeof(SubClass)) 
    Console.WriteLine("bc created from Subclass");
```

#### elaborate more

I see you have a list of base classes, and you want to select an object by its type ... suppose the following classes

```cs
public class Organism { public string? Name; }
public class Person : Organism { }
public class Animal : Organism { }
public class Cat : Animal { }
public class Dog : Animal { }
public class Horse : Animal { }
```

and you have list of `Organism`

```cs
List<Organism> organisms = [
     new Person{Name="ibram"},
     new Cat(){Name ="memo"},
     new Horse{Name="flash"}
    ];
```

examin the following queries

```cs
organisms.Where(organism => organism is Animal); // will return [Cat(memo), Horse(flash)]
organisms.Where(organism => organism.GetType() == typeof(Animal)); // return empty [] there is no object in list created from animal
organisms.Where(organism => organism.GetType() == typeof(Cat)); // will return [Cat(memo)] 
organisms.Where(organism => organism is Person); // will return [Person(ibram)]
```

Comment: This does not "discover which subclass it was before", just that it can be cast to the given type.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for collaboration for more clarity... you are completely right

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is` operator instead of 'was' in your if statement:

It checks wether an object is compatible with a given type and returns true if the object is compatible; otherwise, returns false.

Additionally you have to write `Console.WriteLine()` instead of 'print'.

Comment: This does not "discover which subclass it was before", just that it can be cast to the given type.